# Detect if mouse is on top or bottom half of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have javascript/jquery code that will allow the user to drag/drop records to re-sort them. But currently it always sorts the item above whatever item they move it to.

I would like for it to sort above if the mouse is on the top half, and below if the mouse is on the bottom half. And I would like to show a line or border that indicates which side it will be sorted to based on where the mouse currently is.

The only part of this process I'm not sure of is how to tell if the mouse is on the top or bottom half of an element. I suspect I will need to do some math to divide the height by 2 and then see if the relative y coordinate of the mouse in the element is above or below that number.

As I'm writing this, I'm thinking perhaps the title should reflect specifically that I want to know how to get the relative coordinate of the mouse in an element, but I also know when I'm too specific then I end up having to explain the bigger picture anyway as there are often alternative solutions that are better. So there you have the big picture and the specific way I think I need to solve the problem.

Comment: What about creating an (invisible) overlay that defines the drag zones you want?

Comment: @Allan Wind I actually did think about that but I think taking the y offset divided by two will be simpler as Rich pointed out. I suppose I should have known such a property existed on the drag/drop interface but I didn't previously realize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn’t specify if you’re using the [HTML Drag and Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) interface, but assuming you are, you could use the drop event object to get the mouse (or touch) offsetY  position and compare that to the height of your target element. If  the offsetY is more than half the height of the target, append your record after the target element, and if not append your record after the previousSibling.

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var target = ev.currentTarget;
  var domRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("offsetY: " + ev.offsetY + " height: " + domRect.height);
  // do the logic and append your record to the right position
}
```

And if you're not use the HTML Drag and Drop interface, the concept of comparing the event offsetY to your drop target should still be possible.

Comment: This is a good solution, but if you have child elements inside the drop area then offsetY will return the offset relative to the child rather than the container. You can account for this by calculating the offset like this: ev.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - ev.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top + ev.offsetY.